# Scale with major, minor, diminshed and augmented chords in it

Tags: chords, scales, chord-theory, tetrachords

I am looking for a well-known example of a scale, which has a minor, major, diminished and augmented chord in it. I mean the following: When I write down the scale and write down the triad on every note of that scale, there should be a minor, major, diminished and augmented chord. Is there a frequently used scale, which has this property?

Comment: You might be interested in the concept of an interval vector.  It's a summary of the interval content of a pitch class set.  (A scale is a pitch class set.)  It wouldn't necessarily tell you which triads you can form, but it can give you a good idea of what the melodic possibilities are.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_vector

Comment: Both the harmonic and melodic minor scales are in common use in many minor songs, and all exam boards use them. How far did your own research go?

Comment: Thanks. I could verify, what was written in the answer below. In addition: Isn't harmonic major - for example F-G-A-Bb-C-Db-E-F - another example? Major on 1 and 5, Minor on 3 and 4, Diminished on 2 and 7, Augmented on 6 ?

Comment: Also any scale of the "Heptatonica Secunda" - the modes of melodic minor - will have every of these chords, i.e. Ionian #1, Dorian #7, Phrygian #6, Lydian #5, Mixolydian #4, Aeolian #3, Locrian #2, which are better known under different names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **harmonic minor** scale has all four.

- Major chords built on 5 and b6
- Minor chords built on 1 and 4
- Diminished chords built on 2 and 7
- Augmented chord built on b3

The **melodic minor** ascending scale.

- Major chords built on 4 and 5
- Minor chords built on 1 and 2
- Diminished chord built on 6 and 7
- Augmented chord built on b3

The **double harmonic** scale (with a little bit of fudging in how the chords are formed).

- Major chords built on 1, b2 and 3
- Minor chords built on b2, 3 and 4
- Diminished chord built on b2 and 4
- Augmented chord built on 1, 3 and b6

(Note that some scale degrees [1, b2, 3 and 4] can make more than one triad, while others [5 and 7] cannot make any triads.)

The **chromatic scale** trivially contains all four chord types.

The **Lydian Dominant**, which can play a prominent role in jazz, has all four.

`1 2 3 #4 5 6 b7`

`C-D-E-F#-G-A-Bb`

```
   dim   aug
  |----|----|
C E G Bb D F# A
|---|----|
 maj  min
```

Other scales can be constructed. For example:

`1 #2 3 #4 5 6 7`

`C D# E F# G A B`

- Major on 1 and 7
- Diminished on 2 and 4
- Minor on 3 and 6
- Augmented on 5

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I'll give it a try later and check your answer as soon as I've figured this out!

Comment: Isn't harmonic major - for example F-G-A-Bb-C-Db-E-F - another example? Major on 1 and 5, Minor on 3 and 4, Diminished on 2 and 7, Augmented on 6 ?

Comment: @user408858 Yes. Harmonic major also works as you describe.